# Understanding how Lambda function and foldl work in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda

I am currently learning Haskell, and I have run into not so much a problem but a point of confusion. I'm looking at examples from the e-book 
"Learn you a Haskell". (http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) and there is an example of a lambda function and foldl that I don't quite understand.
So, in the example the code provided to re-create the reverse function is as follows:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
reverse' = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) []
```

Which I have compiled, and run succesfully. However I don't understand why you don't need to specify where the list is coming from like so:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
reverse' e = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) [] e
```

(Where e would be the list [a] from the user input).

Can someone explain this, or even point me to a document that explains it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [η-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion): in lambda calculus (and thus in Haskell) you can replace `\x -> f x` with simply `f`. Combine that with the fact that function definitions are actually syntactic sugar:

```
g x = f x
```

is sugar for

```
g = \x -> f x
```

so it's just

```
g = f
```

Applied to your example,

```
reverse' e = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) [] e
⇌
reverse' = \e -> foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) [] e
⇌
reverse' = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) []
```

This idea of ommitting function arguments which are merely passed on to some other function is called [point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Point-free). It's pretty often used in Haskell and can make your code quite a bit more concise, as well as sometimes revealing more general mathematical structure. It may however also make your code somewhat cryptic (derogatory term: *pointless style*).